# Django remote server is running but I cannot connect to admin interface in local web browser

Tags: django, server, remote-server

So I have set up my Django server through an SSH connection to my remote server. It shows me that the server is actually running:

> August 10, 2020 - 04:09:47
> Django version 3.1, using settings 'risk_areas.settings'
> Starting development server at http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000/
> Quit the server with CONTROL-C

However, if I try to go to the URL above (with my IP address in it) it gives me a connection time out error. What might be the reason for this?

Comment: how did you run your server?

Comment: I think I found the issue. It seems that my firewall does not open port 8000. My server provider will do that for me now. Let's see

Comment: do not run runserver in production as it might be insecure, use proper deployment options https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/